# ESS set tab whitespace level?

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I thought you set the level of indentation with

```
(setq ess-indent-level 2)
```

But I keep getting 4 spaces. For instance, I used to write

```
foo <- function(x)
  x + 2
```

But now, ESS puts the second line 4 spaces away from the left margin

```
foo <- function(x)
    x + 2
```

Has something changed between the new and old versions? I used to use ESS 5.11 and just upgraded to 13.05(!).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, many things have changed since 5.11. The default indentation style now follows R
standard 4 spaces for indentation. Choose the best style from `ess-style-alist`
and set `ess-default-style`:

```
(setq ess-default-style 'OWN)
```

To return to old default and make the settings honor individual variables like
`ess-indent-level` add this:

```
(setq ess-default-style 'DEFAULT)
```

Somewhat confusing, the name DEFAULT comes from `default-value`, that is the style
is build from the default settings of indentation variables like
`ess-indent-level`, `ess-arg-function-offset`, `ess-brace-offset`
etc.

FWIW, you can change indentation syles interactively with <kbd>C-c .</kbd> (<kbd>C-c C-e C-s</kbd> as of 2014).

Comment: as of 2019 you would use `(setq ess-style 'Rstudio)`

Comment: Now it is also possible to customize `ess-default-style`.

Comment: @loki Should that be `(setq ess-style 'RStudio)` (i.e., capital 'S')?